# Filtro em um Select MYSQL via PHP (ionic 3)

Tags: php, mysql, ionic

Boa tarde a todos, antes de explicar um pouco mais sobre a dúvida eu gostaria de deixar claro que sou bem leigo no assunto e, por incrível que pareça, estou a semanas tentando resolver esse problema. 
Dúvida: Eu gostaria de listar alguns dados do meu BD, no caso o usuário iria digitar uma data e o sistema iria listar apenas registros que contém essa data, como se fosse um filtro. Após vários testes só consegui fazer um listar simples, sem nenhum filtro, segue os códigos:(home.ts)

```
    carregarProdutos(){

  this.produtoProvider.getAll()
  .then(data => {
    this.produtos = data;

  });

}
```

**produtos.ts(provider)**

```
  getAll() {
return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.http.get(this.URL+'/produto').subscribe(data => {
    resolve(data);
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
}
```

**Index.php**

```
$app->get('/produto/', function() use ($app){
   (new \controllers\Produto($app))->lista();
});
```

**Controller produto.php**

```
        public function lista(){
            global $app;
            $sth = $this->PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM produtos");
            $sth->execute();
            $result = $sth->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $app->render('default.php',["data"=>$result],200); 
        }
```

Como eu disse esse código está funcionando, porém não consigo de maneira alguma fazer o transporte de variável para que fique assim:

```
$sth = $this->PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE data= :data");
$sth ->bindValue(':data',$data);
```

Novamente me desculpe, mas sou realmente leigo no assunto.

Comment: Qual a framework que está a suar em PHP.

Comment: API RESTful com PHP Slim Framework, seria isso?

Comment: Segue o git: https://github.com/ClubeDosGeeksCoding/api-php-slim-framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode passar a data como um parâmetro na sua rota

Do lado do cliente, adiciona método com um parâmetro data para pesquisa por data, no url do pedido http passa data: */produto/'+ data*

```
getAllByDate(data) {
return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.http.get(this.URL+'/produto/'+ data).subscribe(data => {
    resolve(data);
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
}
```

Do lado do servidor, adiciona uma rota com o parâmetro data,  *{data}*

```
$app->get('/produto/{data}', function($request, $response, $args) use ($app){

   //o valor da data é passado no array $args
   (new \controllers\Produto($app))->lista($args['data']);
});

    //data é passada como argumento para o seu método
    public function lista($data){
        global $app;
        $sth = $this->PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE               data= :data");

       $sth ->bindValue(':data',$data);
        $sth->execute();
        $result = $sth->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $app->render('default.php',["data"=>$result],200); 
    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! Logo irei testar, mas agradeço desde já.

Comment: Uma dúvida, eu consigo declarar a variável assim?  data= "2018-07-20"; 
Caso sim eu estou tendo um problema, segue o link: [link](https://scontent.fplu3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/37400334_640043676363110_8064936292456071168_n.png?_nc_cat=0&_nc_eui2=AeGVBPw68AoJ-uEdgcMLuqfJwqtkX-ElOnoUajXYSplCwkLnXE_1m3fdzdKWYiED4zYWzcQ3ACIc8wMJBiD1uGZRCEHiGy_SqngXWu6Xh9od1g&oh=560ce0415f716b9755557708b7231fbf&oe=5BE5F6CB) simplesmente dá essa mensagem no console e não lista nada.

Comment: Você pode testar a sua api directamente sem usar o front-end basta colocar o mesmo URL no browser e testar a resposta

Comment: Esqueci desse detalhe, mil desculpas. [link](https://scontent.fplu3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/37551969_640105976356880_4921362343109066752_n.png?_nc_cat=0&_nc_eui2=AeHnSqz35D1fuYMlm3e0OBL1wg9X3266H11cnWJuj_H-UpStbVNedvHefgmJ9xbu9F9__JMLmq7TVElXzvZCF-k_UYdUbUSePk1PsscEmSsusA&oh=34db23d8a99f404496014e5cea79e37f&oe=5BCCB385)

Comment: Não se esqueça que data tem que estar entre pelicas ‘2018-02-12’ por exemplo

Comment: Sim, segue o código do home.ts:
data= "2018-07-20";
carregarProdutos(){
   
    this.produtoProvider.getAll(this.data)
    .then(data => {
      this.produtos = data;
     
    });

  }

Comment: Isole o problema primeiro garanta a api no servidor, fazendo o pedido directamente no browser. Aliás você deve manter a api anterior e também testar no browser para verificar se está o obter algum erro, se a resposta estiver correcta avança para o front-end

Comment: Irei quebrar um pouco mais a cabeça então haha. Muito obrigado por tudo cara.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro de tudo eu gostaria de agradecer o Jorge, ele me ajudou muito na resolução. Vou explanar aqui como ficou o código funcional.
index.php

```
$app->get('/produto/:datad', function($datad) use ($app){
(new \controllers\Produto($app))->lista($datad);
```

});
Controller:

```
public function lista($datad){
    global $app;
    $sth = $this->PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM consumo_atual where data_criacao = :data");
    $sth ->bindValue(':data',$datad);
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $app->render('default.php',["data"=>$result],200); 
}
```

Agora meu único problema é na listagem dos dados no próprio TS, mas de qualquer forma deixo o registro a todos que possam ter essa dúvida futuramente.